# List in Javascript throws an unexpected error

Tags: javascript

```
   var ItemList = {
        0:{name:"Cat%27s%20Pajamas",quality:"Unique"},
        1:{name:"C.A.P.P.E.R",quality:"Unique"},
        2:{name:"Head%20Prize",quality:"Unique"},
        3:{name:"Bedouin%20Bandana",quality:"Unique"},
        4:{name:"Spine-Chilling%20Skull",quality:"Unique"},
        5:{name:"Voodoo%20Juju",quality:"Unique"},
        6:{name:"Australium%20Blutsauger",quality:"Strange"},
        7:{name:"Australium%20Axtinguisher",quality:"Strange"},
        8:{name:"Australium%20SMG",quality:"Strange"},
        9:{name:"Australium%20Ambassador",quality:"Strange"},
        10:{name:"Australium%20Force-A-Nature",quality:"Strange"},
        11:{name:"Australium%20Black%20Box",quality:"Strange"},
        12:{name:"Australium%20Frontier%20Justice",quality:"Strange"},
        13:{name:"Australium%20Grenade%20Launcher",quality:"Strange"},
        14:{name:"Australium%20Knife",quality:"Strange"},
        15:{name:"Australium%20Stickybomb%20Launcher",quality:"Strange"},
        16:{name:"Dead%20Head",quality:"Unique"},
        17:{name:"Australium%20Flame%20Thrower",quality:"Strange"},
        18:{name:"Australium%20Tomislav",quality:"Strange"},
        19:{name:"Max%27s%20Severed%20Head",quality:"Unique"},
        20:{name:"Australium%20Minigun",quality:"Strange"},
        21:{name:"Australium%20Sniper%20Rifle",quality:"Strange"},
        22:{name:"Australium%20Scattergun",quality:"Strange"},
        23:{name:"Australium%20Rocket%20Launcher",quality:"Strange"},
        24:{name:"Towering%20Pillar%20of%20Summer%20Shades",quality:"Unique"},
        25:{name:"Australium%20Wrench",quality:"Strange"},
        26:{name:"Ghastlierest%20Gibus",quality:"Strange"},
        27:{name:"Australium%20Medi%20Gun",quality:"Strange"},
        28:{name:"Australium%20Eyelander",quality:"Strange"},
        29:{name:"Hat%20of%20Undeniable%20Wealth%20And%20Respect",quality:"Unique"}
    }

console.log(ItemList.length);
```

Basically I have this code with a list. What I trying to do is just print the length of that list. When I run in I get an error: `Undefined main.js:34`. What does that mean, like the list is defined so I don't see the problem.
The 34th line is `console.log(ItemList.length);` any ideas?

Comment: JS objects do not have a `length` property.

Comment: You could use `Object.keys(ItemList).length`

Comment: @Nick TBH, seems more like OP needs to use an array, rather than a plain object

Comment: @VLAZ agreed, but for what they *have*, the duplicate is appropriate

Comment: @Nick what I'm trying to get at is that it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @VLAZ ah, sorry, too early in the morning... but if, as you say, it is an XY problem, then this question should be closed and they should ask another question about how to make an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is a javascript object. Only javascript arrays have the `length` property. However, you can easily convert it into an array like this:

```js
var ItemList = {
  0: {
    name: "Cat%27s%20Pajamas",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  1: {
    name: "C.A.P.P.E.R",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  2: {
    name: "Head%20Prize",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  3: {
    name: "Bedouin%20Bandana",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  4: {
    name: "Spine-Chilling%20Skull",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  5: {
    name: "Voodoo%20Juju",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  6: {
    name: "Australium%20Blutsauger",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  7: {
    name: "Australium%20Axtinguisher",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  8: {
    name: "Australium%20SMG",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  9: {
    name: "Australium%20Ambassador",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  10: {
    name: "Australium%20Force-A-Nature",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  11: {
    name: "Australium%20Black%20Box",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  12: {
    name: "Australium%20Frontier%20Justice",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  13: {
    name: "Australium%20Grenade%20Launcher",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  14: {
    name: "Australium%20Knife",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  15: {
    name: "Australium%20Stickybomb%20Launcher",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  16: {
    name: "Dead%20Head",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  17: {
    name: "Australium%20Flame%20Thrower",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  18: {
    name: "Australium%20Tomislav",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  19: {
    name: "Max%27s%20Severed%20Head",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  20: {
    name: "Australium%20Minigun",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  21: {
    name: "Australium%20Sniper%20Rifle",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  22: {
    name: "Australium%20Scattergun",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  23: {
    name: "Australium%20Rocket%20Launcher",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  24: {
    name: "Towering%20Pillar%20of%20Summer%20Shades",
    quality: "Unique"
  },
  25: {
    name: "Australium%20Wrench",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  26: {
    name: "Ghastlierest%20Gibus",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  27: {
    name: "Australium%20Medi%20Gun",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  28: {
    name: "Australium%20Eyelander",
    quality: "Strange"
  },
  29: {
    name: "Hat%20of%20Undeniable%20Wealth%20And%20Respect",
    quality: "Unique"
  }
}

console.log("Length: %o", Object.values(ItemList).length);
console.log(Object.values(ItemList));
```